# What's the difference between a time crystal and a system undergoing periodic motion?

Tags: terminology, crystals, time-crystals, harmonic-oscillator

What's the difference between a [time crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_crystal) and a system undergoing periodic motion? My understanding of a crystal is that it is a rigid body with a spatially periodic structure. Is any system undergoing periodic motion a time crystal, or is there some other requirement that makes it special? In other words, what (if anything) excludes the ideal simple harmonic oscillator from the category of time crystal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A crystal is a system which spontaneously breaks the translation symmetry of the underlying physical laws.

Similarly, a time crystal is a system which is subject to a periodic driving with period $T$, but which however does not oscillate with the same period but shows oscillations which a different period $T'=kT$ with $k>1$ integer, i.e., which spontaneously breaks the (discrete) time translation symmetry.

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/309142/4888) provides a very nice explanation of time crystals.

Comment: Naive (and redundant) question but just to confirm, a system with time-independent Hamiltonian that shows oscillations with some time-period $T>0$ still won't be a time-crystal as long as there is no spontaneous symmetry breaking of time-translational symmetry, right?