# What are Time Crytals?

Tags: symmetry, time-crystals

I am a physics enthusiast and came upon an article regarding time crystals and didn't understand many things.

What exactly are [Time Crystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_crystal)? and what sets them apart from Normal crystals?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_crystal ?

Comment: 1)  https://www.sciencealert.com/scientists-have-just-announced-a-brand-new-form-of-matter-time-crystals   2) https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.sciencealert.com/time-crystal-signatures-found-in-extremely-common-compound-monoammonium-phosphate&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjszuq-k-_aAhVMQY8KHbLODioQFggIMAE&client=internal-uds-cse&cx=009882534323254498007:0ejrj_dbalc&usg=AOvVaw28LVbnUpXEGuVypNJPOPDH

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding time crystals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308403/)